# Is it possible to inspect CSS3 animation keyframes with a browser inspector?

Tags: css, browser, css-animations, web-inspector

I have encountered a few sites, now, that take advantage of CSS3 keyframe-style animation, and decided to test it on my own sites. However, this leads me to a conundrum: Usually before I commit a CSS file to the site, I'll use the browser's inspector (`Ctrl+Shift+I` on Chrome, Opera, and FF; `F12` in IE) to tweack and change the CSS locally to see what I like best. However, it appears there's no way to change the keyframes of a CSS3 animation with the browser inspector! This is an extreme hinderance to me, as it forces me to commit a CSS file every time I want to change any nuance of the animation, which also comes with up to a 15-minute delay from the server. **Is there any way I can locally change CSS3 animation keyframes with the browser inspector?**

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Huzzah hoorah and hooray! It's completely possible today! Chrome Dev Tools added an Animation tool! Just open up the dev tools and click the "More Tools" button, then "Animations", and a whole suite of cool tools are available for debugging animations

[image: Chrome dev tools 'More Tools' icon - three vertically-stacked dots which have the tooltip text 'More Tools']

[image: The menu which results from pressing the 'More Tools' button, showing the 'Animations' option selected]

[image: Google Chrome, open to BenLeggiero.me with the animation inspector showing.]

Comment: @MeltingDog I haven't had time to update the answer, but this was moved from an icon in the toolbar to a menu item in the secondary inspector thing (y'know that thing that appears when you hit escape?).

Comment: Was finally able to update the answer  Now it reflects reality

Answer (score 18):

Since Chrome 50 it's now finally possible to edit CSS keyframes.
https://twitter.com/ChromeDevTools/status/694966453376675840
[image]

Comment: What does this add that my answer doesn't?

Comment: The animation editor allows you to edit only the animation-delay and animation-duration, but not keyframes.

Comment: Beautiful! I love that these are now editable as well as inspectable :)

Comment: Could it be that this option is now gone? Can't find keyframe definitions either there or in the Animations tab.

Answer (score 14):

**On Chrome:**
 - Ctrl+Shift+I
 - Choose an element
 - right column: click on the css-link (for example style.css:24)
 - Now you can edit your css-file

Notes:
- You can't edit css in the right column and in the css-file at the same time
- To retrigger the animation, remove -webkit-animation:... and add it back

Comment: Interesting workaround. It works, but it's a bit of a hassle :P
Any solutions for Opera, FF, Safari, or IE? That's all that's keeping me from accepting

Comment: ammendment: Opera answer no longer needed

Comment: I believe it's the fastest way for extracting animation keyframes.

Answer (score 4):

If you want even more control, download Chrome Canary (64bit required I believe).  There is a little 'play' button and a time adjustment so you can slow down the animation and pause it whenever you want.  Pretty cool!

[image: illustrative screenshot]
[Instructional video](http://tjohns.co/web-development/34-google-chrome)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and effort to answer, but it didn't really answer my question.

Comment: Yea... there's no way to actually see the keyframes in the inspector.  So, I guess the final answer there is 'no'.  I basically take my keyframe styles and put them into the main element and adjust them in inspector.  That should work fine except for your 15 minute server delay.  I think that's the bigger problem.

Answer (score 4):

Soon it will be, through the Chrome Dev Tools' Animation Timeline.

So far there's only this teaser video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U9xfYbKxosI

Comment: Wow, that looks like everything i need and more! I can't wait!

Answer (score 2):

It took a while to get this on Chrome since most options have been moved or changed.

This is the way to get it on chrome in 4 steps illustrated on the screenshot below :

[image]

On Firefox (developer edition), there is a conspicuous Animation Tab as shown below:

[image]